# How do i fix pip installation problems

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

```
C:\Users\awmvi>pip install numpy
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))': /simple/numpy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))': /simple/numpy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))': /simple/numpy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))': /simple/numpy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))': /simple/numpy/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy
```

This error pops out whenever i try to install anything

i am using windows 11
python 3.11.5

i  tried installing numpy

Comment: how did you install python?

Comment: use `python3 -m pip install numpy`

Comment: It still don't work

Comment: Can you provide more context to your question?
How did you install Python? Did you download it from 'https://www.python.org/'? Is pip installed? Can you check which version is installed 'pip --version' Are you sat behind a proxy? You can download packages from Pypi.org and install the wheel file locally